# C++ based mac/win app wtih UI

Tags: macos

I need to develop a server app for mac and for windows (mainly sockets, file transfers and one Window with some check boxes), the app needs to have a small foot print.
I am aware of QT framework as portbale, unfortunately my app will have quite a big footprint in that case as it requires shipping libs along with for win/mac. So I am not considering QT. I am expecting at most 1MB foot print which I think is not possible wtih QT (please correct me if my understanding about QT libs is wrong that they are big in size)

So here is my question

if I choose standard C++ as my language would I be able to create a bit of UI with it in MAC ? beacuse my understanding is that cocoa is the UI framework on mac which is in ObjectiveC, so I am not sure if I can create minimalistic UI (one window and few chack boxes ) with C++ on mac.

Thanks,

Comment: Although the frameworks require Objective-C for UI code, the Objective-C++ compiler does not preclude use of C++ for everything else.  You can either partition your code into appropriately-named files or use `#ifdef __OBJC__` to combine languages in one header file.

Comment: Kevin are you saying I can mix objective C code in C++ and have one binary file in the end ?

Comment: On Mac OS X you can do this, yes.  For example, one file can be named `File1.mm` and contain a mixture of Objective-C and C++; another file might be `File2.cp` and be pure C++; both can be compiled into a project and share the final binary.  In header files  that contain Objective-C however, you need to "protect" the Objective-C parts (with `#ifdef __OBJC__`) in order to include those headers from pure-C++ files.